# Post object GUID adding http:/

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, guids

In my template I have `href="'.$package_link->guid.'"`

The resulting HTML is: `href="http:/package/download-2023-friday-arrival-monday-departure-weekend-coach-festival-ticket/"`

Why is the `http:/` being added? I am using Advanced Custom Fields with the field setup as below. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should not be using the GUID as a link](https://pods.io/2013/07/17/dont-use-the-guid-field-ever-ever-ever/). If you want to get the URL for a WordPress post object you should use [`get_the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/):

```
href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink( $package_link ) ) . '"
```

Note that I also [escaped](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/) the URL.